# IPTables: drop packets with a certain DCSP value

Tags: iptables, qos

I can find a lot of examples on how to classify traffic for QoS using TOS and DCSP, but I can't seem to find examples which filter based on the QoS values set.

What I want to do is drop all traffic unless the DCSP flag is set to one.

Comment: Do you mean the TOS (DSCP) field of IPv4 header?

Comment: @Khaled yes correct, what I want is only traffic to pass that has a certain DSCP value set (e.g. 1)

Answer (score 2):

There is an iptables module `dscp` that seems to do what you need. If you don't have any rules in current iptables setup, you can do something like:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m dscp --dscp 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

You may need to allow `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` traffic also. The above rules are applied to `FORWARD` chain. You can do similarly for `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` chains if required.